# SUM OF Parent Raise SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

HI I have two table like this

```
TBL 1

Productid  Childid 
     1     null
     2      1
     3      1
     4      1
     5     null
     6      5 
     7      6 
     8      null

Tbl 2
Productid      amount
      1        300
      2        100
      2        100
      2        300
      5        100
```

As you can see  product 1 is parent and it has 2,3,4 child and it Raise 500 from child and 300 from Parents . That means 1 Raise 800 in total . now i want This type of Result

```
SQL :
SELECT t1.productid as pid, SUM(t3.amount) as amount
FROM TBL1 t1
JOIN TBL1 t2 
 ON(t1.productid = t2.childid)
JOIN TBL2 t3
 ON(t3.productid IN(t2.childID,t2.productID))
GROUP BY t1.productid

RESULT 
pid amount 

NULL 900
```

But i want Like This

```
RESULT 
pid amount 
1     800
5     100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select t1.productid as pid, sum(t3.amount) as amount
from tbl1 t1
inner join (
    select productid, coalesce(childid, productid) as childid from tbl1
) t2
on t1.productid = t2.childid
inner join tbl2 t3
on t2.productid = t3.productid
group by t1.productid
```

### SQLFiddle Demo

***EDITED:***

```
select t1.productid as pid, sum(t3.amount) as amount
from tbl1 t1
inner join tbl1 t2
-- inner join (
--    select productid, coalesce(childid, productid) as childid from tbl1
-- ) t2
on t1.productid = coalesce(t2.childid, t2.productid)
inner join tbl2 t3
on t2.productid = t3.productid
group by t1.productid
```

### SQLFiddle Demo

Comment: Thanks Its working . Is their another way without using Nested Select to optimaze huge data

Comment: Of course, check my ***EDITED*** answer. @KakulSarma

Comment: thanks a lots . kindly vote up my q also hope it will help more people

Answer (score 0):

Here you go..

```
SELECT t1.productid as pid, SUM(t3.amount) as amount
FROM TBL1 t1
JOIN TBL1 t2 
 ON(t1.productid = t2.childid)
JOIN TBL2 t3
 ON(t3.productid = t1.productID)
GROUP BY t1.productid
```